# How do I change a variable every so minutes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

I want to display a random record from the database for a certain amount of time, after that time it gets refreshed to another random record.

How would I go about that in rails?

Right now I'm looking in the directions of cronjobs, also the whenever gem, .. but I'm not 100% sure I really need all that for what seems to be a pretty simple action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Rails.cache mechanism.

In your controller:

```
@record = Rails.cache("cached_record", :expires_in => 5.minutes) do
  Model.first( :offset =>rand(Model.count))
end
```

During the first execution, result gets cached in the Rails cache. A new random record is retrieved after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I would have an expiry_date in my model and then present the user with a javascript timer. After the time has elapsed, i would send a request back to the server(ajax probably, or maybe refreshing the page) and check whether the time has indeed expired. If so, i would present the new record.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check the current time in your controller, something like:

```
def show
  @last_refresh ||= DateTime.now
  @current ||= MyModel.get_random
  @current = MyModel.get_random if (DateTime.now - @last_refresh) > 5.minutes
end
```

This kind of code wouldn't scale to more servers (as it relies on class variables for data storage), so in reality you would wan't to store the two class variables in something like Redis (or Memcache even) - that is for high performance. Depends really on how accurately you need this and how much performance you need. You could as well use your normal database to store expiry times and then load the record whose time is current.

Comment: just a small notice to say that there is no check by the server in this example. If you care about security, you should check it against a server stored value, like a model attribute.

Answer (score 0):

My first though was to cache the record in a global, but you could end up with different records being served by different servers. How about adding a :chosen_at datetime column to your record...

```
class Model < AR::Base

  def self.random
    @@random = first(:conditions => 'chosen_at NOT NULL')
    return @@random unless @@random.nil? or @@random.chosen_at < 5.minutes.ago
    @@random.update_attribute(:chosen_at,nil) if @@random
    ids = connection.select_all("SELECT id FROM things")
    @@random = find(ids[rand(ids.length)]["id"].to_i)
  end

end
```